# Is 'The world is paying the price of corrupted governments.' a consistent statement?

Tags: prepositional-phrases

Let consider such a statement:

> The world is paying the price of corrupted governments.

Do you think it is consistent?

I ask because it seems as there is something missing there, as, for example, 'actions' or 'policy' after 'governments' — in the lack of them that statement appears improperly broken.

Comment: Can you include the source of the sentence? Did you write it yourself? We have to know full context to see whether it is consistent with anything.

Comment: Hello @Ratho, 'consistent' in the question means 'selfconsistent'. Do you think I should edit such a word to make it clear?

Comment: First of all, there is no harm in saying that you wrote the sentence yourself or found it somewhere i.e. in a newspaper/internet article or book. . Second, corrupted government is not idiomatic compared with **corrupt government**, third **paying the price of** is not idiomatic compared with **paying the price for** if government (action or policy) is the cause of the price.

Comment: [Both *paying the price of* and *paying the price for* are in common usage](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=paying+the+price+*), although as a native speaker I think *paying the price for* sounds better.

Comment: @stangdon If you contrast "He paid the price of his life" with "He paid the price for his life", the meaning is different.

Comment: Either can be used in the sense of "We have corrupt government, and now we are paying the price."  For example, "[...they paid the price of not doing the right thing](https://books.google.com/books?id=l1dSLZG8NhEC&lpg=PA100&ots=_JhiddIZNz&dq=%22they%20paid%20the%20price%20of%22&pg=PA100#v=onepage&q=%22they%20paid%20the%20price%20of%22&f=false)" and "[They paid the price for their lack of trust in God](https://books.google.com/books?id=vatKAwAAQBAJ&lpg=PA49&dq=%22they%20paid%20the%20price%20for%22&pg=PA49#v=onepage&q=%22they%20paid%20the%20price%20for%22&f=false)".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably a corrupt government imposes costs on people. There are literal financial costs, money lost to bribery and cronyism. And there are costs in freedom, justice, and so on.

Yes, you could say "the actions of corrupt governments" or "the policies of corrupt governments. But it's not necessary, and wouldn't really change the meaning of the sentence. The government is corrupt, and this corruption causes problems that the world must deal with.

As others have noted, it is more idiomatic to say "corrupt governments" than "corrupted governments". It is possible that the writer is making some distinction in context. "Corrupt" means that it is corrupt now, with no indication of past state. "Corrupted" implies that at one time it was not corrupt, but now it has become corrupt. This may or may not be a significant distinction, depending on the overall context.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to say that **corrupted governments** exact a burden upon society:

> The world is paying **for** the price **of** corrupted governments
>   The world is paying **for** corrupted governments
>   The world is paying a heavy price **by having** corrupt governments

all have the same meaning of **a toll on the world**

> The world is paying the price **of** corrupted governments.

Does not sound quite right, though would be understandable.